# SQLiteException

Tags: android, database

```
public static final String GTABLE_CREATE = "create table grades (id integer primary key autoincrement, " + 
"coursegrade text not null, c_id text not null, type text not null);";
```

In this code I get a runtime error, which says `SQLiteException` and there is a syntax error 
I do not know what causes this error.

Comment: The SQL Syntax looks fine to me. Could you put in some more details on what you are trying, stack trace, some parts of the code causing this.

Comment: post your error logcat..

Comment: +1 @Tech.Rahul. Post that call trace Yavuz.

Comment: (1) near "create": syntax error                                   Error inserting c_id=rt - 136 type=Midterm coursegrade=rt - 136 Midterm                                                                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "create": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO create table grades (sid integer primary key autoincrement, coursegrade text not null, c_id text not null, type text not null);(c_id,type,coursegrade) VALUES (?,?,?)                                                               is the error log.

Answer (score 0):

try using some other column name instead of id(in your first column name).

Answer (score 0):

try this code.. wrks fine with me..

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE =   
        "create table if not exists registration(_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                +"name varchar(50), address varchar(50) not null, apt_no varchar(50), city varchar(50) not null,"
                +"state varchar(50),  county  varchar(50),  zipcode  varchar(50)  ,"  
                +"property_value  varchar(50) not null, property_type varchar(50) );";
```

hope this ll help you..

Comment: after doing this.. uninstall your app first.. then run your code to install fresh copy..